# Access to XMLHttpRequest at ... from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: php, laravel

Getting a cors issue on Laravel again. No code has been changed and it was all working last night, but somehow its found a way to break itself. This happened after switching domains but the code has remained the same

Middleware:

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $requestOrigin = $request->headers->get('origin');

        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $requestOrigin)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    }
}
```

I am registering the middleware in the global scope, to be run on every HTTP request.

The full error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Checked the error logs, nothing. I removed the conditional check and an origin array to test just the header logic.